# apt-cacher-ng with https package, release does not have release file

Tags: debian, apt, cache

I have setup an apt-cacher-ng and configured it to works with https.

On most https/http package apt update works.

Into apt-cacher-ng server conf i added

```
PassThroughPattern: .*
```

and for each https repository i created a remapping config as following example:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 fake_repo.cache.internal" >> /etc/hosts
echo "https://real.repo.org" > /etc/apt-cacher-ng/backend_real_repo
echo "Remap-gocd: http://fake_repo.cache.internal ; file:backend_real_repo" >> /etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf
```

But for one specific repository :

```
deb https://download.gocd.org /
```

As i transform onto apt-cacher-ng server:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 gocd.cache.internal" >> /etc/hosts
echo "https://download.gocd.org" > /etc/apt-cacher-ng/backend_gocd
echo "Remap-gocd: http://gocd.cache.internal ; file:backend_gocd" >> /etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf
```

**beware of the semicolon, after http://gocd.cache.internal**
**,url must be separated with one space, i spent hours in front of this, and i wasn't able to understand why it doesn't work due to a misplaced semicolon**

and into on client :

```
echo "deb http://gocd.cache.internal /" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list
```

when i run on client :

```
apt update
```

i get the following :

```
Ign :1 http://gocd.cache.internal  InRelease
Atteint :2 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease           
Atteint :3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates 
InRelease
Err :4 http://gocd.cache.internal  Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP : 10.42.30.133 3142]
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
E: Le dépôt http://gocd.cache.internal  Release n'a pas de fichier 
Release.
```

**Release does not have release file.**

Whereas all theses links are working fine

https://download.gocd.org/Release

https://download.gocd.org/Release.gpg

https://download.gocd.org/InRelease

On clients machine i have following config :

```
touch  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01acng

echo "Acquire::http {
        Proxy \"http://apt-cache.mik3fly.internal:3142\";
};" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01acng
```

I m not able determine the cause of the failure

**update :**

I let the original config url on the client and i have no success either

```
deb https://download.gocd/org /
```